# ASM 4.0, renaming Methods in ClassNode

Tags: java, methods, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

Alright, so.  I'm trying to rename methods in a ClassNode in ASM 4.0.

This is my renaming class:

```
public class RenameVisitor extends ClassVisitor {
private String newName,oldName;


public RenameVisitor(String newName,String oldName){
    super(Opcodes.ASM4);
    this.newName = newName;
    this.oldName = oldName;
}
@Override
public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name,
                                 String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
    if(name.contains(oldName)){
        System.out.println(newName);
        return cv.visitMethod(access,newName,desc,signature,exceptions);
    }
    return cv.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
   }
}
```

Now, how would I use this to rename the methods in a classnode?
I tried a few things like:

```
ClassVisitor rv = new RenameVisitor(mn.name,"_"+mn.name);//mn is the method node being tested
ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(node.name);
cr.accept(rv,0);
```

It always throws an error that the class can't be found.  What do I need to do so it can read a ClassNode..?

Answer (score 0):

The [ClassReader JavaDoc](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html#ClassReader%28java.lang.String%29) would be a good place to start. You haven't provided any specifics where your bytecode is coming from, but if you want to use ClassReader constructor with class name, the class should exist in the class path (hence the 'class can't be found' error).